# Aggregate row values in Dataframe under specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` which has two columns. I want to build the sum of all successive rows where value of `column 0` is `-1`.

My `dataframe` looks sth. like this:

```
 0   2
 1   3
-1   4
-1   7
 0   2
-1   0
-1   1
-1   3
 5   0
```

And the desired output should be this:

```
 0   2
 1   3
-1   11
 0   2
-1   4
 5   0
```

the values in the second column are all equal or greater than zero. The values on first column are equal or greater than `-1`, if this helps. My approach would be a loop, where I create second `dataframe` and then push back every value not equal to `-1` and accumulate, when I found a `-1`, but I imagine, this approach would not be efficient. 
Pseudo code:

```
sum = 0
found = False
for row in dataframe:
   if row[0] != -1:
       if found:
           new_df.append([-1, sum])
           sum = 0
           found = False
       new_df.append(row)
   elif row[0] == -1:
       found = True
       sum += row[1]
```

Is there a build-in python or pandas function I can use to achive my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion here is necessary create `Series` for 100% sure if never values of helper groups are same like values outside `-1`, so added `0.5` to `index` for distiguish:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

m = df['a'] == -1
s = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m].reindex(df.index).fillna(df.index.to_series().add(.5))
df = df.groupby(s).agg({'a':'first', 'b':'sum'}).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a   b
0  0   2
1  1   3
2 -1  11
3 -1   4
4  0   2
5  5   0
```

**Explanation**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 5],
                   'b': [2, 3, 4, 7, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0]})
print (df)
   a  b
0  0  2
1  1  3
2 -1  4
3 -1  7
4  0  2
5 -1  0
6 -1  1
7 -1  3
8  5  0
```

First create default index if necessary, because unique index values are used in solution:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then create consecutive groups for `-1` and another values:

```
m = df['a'] == -1
print (df.assign(groups = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()))
   a  b  groups
0  0  2       1
1  1  3       1
2 -1  4       2
3 -1  7       2
4  0  2       3
5 -1  0       4
6 -1  1       4
7 -1  3       4
8  5  0       5
```

Then filter only `-1` values with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) (by mask `b`) and another not matched values convert to `NaN`s  by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
m = df['a'] == -1
print (df.assign(groups = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum(),
                 filtered = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m].reindex(df.index)))

   a  b  groups  filtered
0  0  2       1       NaN
1  1  3       1       NaN
2 -1  4       2       2.0
3 -1  7       2       2.0
4  0  2       3       NaN
5 -1  0       4       4.0
6 -1  1       4       4.0
7 -1  3       4       4.0
8  5  0       5       NaN
```

Then replace missing values by index values with `0.5` - never colise between groups for `-1` and values of replaced `NaN`s:

```
m = df['a'] == -1
print (df.assign(groups = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum(),
                 filtered = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m].reindex(df.index),
                 idx = df.index.to_series().add(.5),
                 groups1 = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m].reindex(df.index).fillna(df.index.to_series().add(.5))))

   a  b  groups  filtered  idx  groups1
0  0  2       1       NaN  0.5      0.5
1  1  3       1       NaN  1.5      1.5
2 -1  4       2       2.0  2.5      2.0
3 -1  7       2       2.0  3.5      2.0
4  0  2       3       NaN  4.5      4.5
5 -1  0       4       4.0  5.5      4.0
6 -1  1       4       4.0  6.5      4.0
7 -1  3       4       4.0  7.5      4.0
8  5  0       5       NaN  8.5      8.5
```

Then is helper `Series` passed to `groupby` and aggregate `sum` for second column and `first` for first column by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and last is removed index by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df = df.groupby(s).agg({'a':'first', 'b':'sum'}).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a   b
0  0   2
1  1   3
2 -1  11
3 -1   4
4  0   2
5  5   0
```

---

Another solution, simplier and also with better performance:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

m = df['a'] == -1
s = df.reset_index()
      .groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m])
      .agg({'index':'first', 'b':'sum'})
      .set_index('index')
      .assign(a = -1)

df = df[~m].append(s, sort=True).sort_index()
print (df)
   a   b
0  0   2
1  1   3
2 -1  11
4  0   2
5 -1   4
8  5   0
```

**Explanation**:

First is necessary default index:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then compare column by `-1` to boolean mask:

```
m = df['a'] == -1
```

Convert index to column by `reset_index` with no `drop` parameter:

```
print (df.reset_index())
   index  a  b
0      0  0  2
1      1  1  3
2      2 -1  4
3      3 -1  7
4      4  0  2
5      5 -1  0
6      6 -1  1
7      7 -1  3
8      8  5  0
```

Create consecutive groups with `shift` and `cumsum` and filter by mask for `-1` groups:

```
print (m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m])
2    2
3    2
5    4
6    4
7    4
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

Aggregate `first` by index column and `sum` by `b` column:

```
print (df.reset_index()
        .groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m])
        .agg({'index':'first', 'b':'sum'}))

     index   b
a             
2.0      2  11
4.0      5   4
```

Convert `index` column to `index` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print(df.reset_index()
      .groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m])
      .agg({'index':'first', 'b':'sum'})
      .set_index('index'))
        b
index    
2      11
5       4
```

Add `a` column with constant `-1` by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
s = (df.reset_index()
      .groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m])
      .agg({'index':'first', 'b':'sum'})
      .set_index('index')
      .assign(a = -1))
print (s)
        b  a
index       
2      11 -1
5       4 -1
```

Last filter out `-1` rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverse mask by `~`:

```
print (df[~m])
  a  b
0  0  2
1  1  3
4  0  2
8  5  0
```

Then add new data to original by [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
print (df[~m].append(s, sort=True))
   a   b
0  0   2
1  1   3
4  0   2
8  5   0
2 -1  11
5 -1   4
```

And last [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for same ordering:

```
print (df[~m].append(s, sort=True).sort_index())
   a   b
0  0   2
1  1   3
2 -1  11
4  0   2
5 -1   4
8  5   0
```

Comment: Could you tell in detail, what happens in every line? I am new to python, but I want to be sure, that I use it correctly and in the best manner possible

Comment: @RoQuOTriX - Added explanation, solution working for any value of first value with `-1`.